# senKeys is not working .Means its just looks copying the text,Not the key event

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am new to `Selenium`. I am using `Selenium IDE v2.4.0`

I am using `sendKeys` command but it looks that it's just pasting the text.

It's not working like type command. I am not getting any suggestion when these keys would be send.

When same thing I am typing in my test box then I am getting suggestion as well.

My Question is why `sendKeys` is not working as expected?

I have tried the below :

```
<tr>
<td>sendKeys</td>
<td>id=arid_WIN_3_1000000054</td>
<td>CMSHELPDESK</td>
</tr>
```

Result: This step is successfully executed but I see that text is present there but no suggestion.

After the above step I wanted to click on suggestion with the below code:-

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>css=font</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Result: Failed because no suggestion is given.

Maybe this is a silly question but I am new to `Selenium`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Selenium IDE and specific Firefox version incompatibility bug, because `sendKeys` actually *should* behave as real keystroke events, according to reference

I would suggest to downgrade your Firefox

Comment: @Aexander Now i am thinking to switch to selenium java web driver.Since   it seems that selenium IDE and Firefox versions are screwing me What do you suggest?

Comment: @samash, good choice. My experience with IDE was quite short, because it lacks some flexibility.